# How to create a separate user base in Django without extending the user model

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

So I am trying to build a website in Django where I want two separate user bases like `users` and `agents`. An `agent` can be an agent without being a `user`. `Agents` have a separate login url and `users` have a separate login url. This is where I am stuck. I can't seem to create a different login page for `agents`. Anyone can apply to be an agent without logging in/registering as a user, then if he/she meets requirements, he/she will be registered as an agent in the admin panel by a `superuser`. Is there any better way to do this?

My models.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    phonenumber = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'

class Agent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'Images/')
    bio = models.TextField()
    instagram = models.URLField(max_length=100)
    twitter = models.URLField(max_length=100)
    facebook = models.URLField(max_length=100)
    linkedin = models.URLField(max_length=100)
    is_featured = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    slug = models.SlugField(default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name} Agent Profile'
```

My forms.py:

```
class AgentSignInForm(AuthenticationForm):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    password = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        username = cleaned_data.get('username')
        password = cleaned_data.get('password')
        return cleaned_data
```

My models.py:

```
class AgentLoginView(LoginView):
    form_class = AgentSignInForm
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.send_email()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

My urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
path('agent-sign-in/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='users/agent_login.html'), name='agent-sign-in'),
]
```

Comment: I think you will have to write custom Authentication Backend and Authentication Middleware. You can check Django's `AuthenticationMiddleware` and `ModelBackend` as an example.

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve the behaviour you want, you have to customize the Django's default authentication.

#### Implementing custom Backend

The Authentication Backend responsible for handling authentication requests and returning the corresponding User model. It also provides an access to User's permissions.

Here is how it might look like:

```py
from contextlib import suppress

from django.contrib.auth.backends import BaseBackend
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import check_password


class AgentBackend(BaseBackend):
    def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None, **kwargs):
        # Skip authentication attempts without credentials
        if username is None or password is None:
            return

        # Get agent by name, check the password hash and return it if everything is ok
        with suppress(Agent.DoesNotExist):  
            agent = Agent.objects.get(name=username)
            if check_password(password, agent.password):
                return agent
        return None

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        # Fetch and return agent if it exists
        with suppress(Agent.DoesNotExist):
            return Agent.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        return None
```

#### Enable new Backend in Settings

In your Django settings you need to enable a new Backend along with the default one.

```py
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    "django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend",
    "path.to.your.backend.AgentBackend",  # <-- Note: this need to be updated to your actual Backend module
]
```

A few notes to keep in mind:

1. The Backend implementation above is simplified and doesn't include permissions. You need to extend it if you need these capabilities.
2. Make sure use never assign a plain password to the model. Use `make_password` function in order to compute a hash.
3. You probably need to extend `Agent.password` field up to 128 characters, otherwise it won't be enough to store a hashed password value.

Further reading:

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/auth/customizing/#authentication-backends
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/auth/passwords/

Comment: what is the path to my backend? what would a generic path look like?

Comment: It is a python module with a backend. Let's say you decide to name your Backend `AgentBackend` and put it in the following file: `app/auth/backends.py`. In this case the path will be `app.auth.backends.AgentBackend`.

Comment: So I did create a backends.py file and copy that `AgentBackend` user model there. But then what about the views? How do I handle that and the `make_password` function? I have increased the `Agent.password` field to 128 characters.

Comment: Even after logging in, how do I write the view of `agent_profile/agent_dashboard` for example. For now, I can't even log in.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question, you want to create a separate UI for 2 user types.
I think it's unnecessary and needs more resources(time+money) to create and manage separate user base modules.

**Method**

1. Use a middle model like below.

```
class Common_user_data(models. Model):
    user_data = models.OneToOneField(User , primary_key=True, on_delete=models. CASCADE)

    user_types=(
        ('1','User'),
        ('2','Agent'),
        )
    user_type = models.CharField(default='1',max_length=1,choices=user_types,null=False,blank=False)
```

2. Then in any child model use as below.

```
class Log(models. Model):
    log_author = models.ForeignKey(Common_user_data, on_delete=models. CASCADE)
```

3. use "user_type"
   attribute to redirect users to "login views", "urls".

in template:-

```
{% if request.user.common_user_data.user_type == "1" %}

or

{{ request.user.common_user_data.user_type }}
```

in views:-

```
if (request.user.common_user_data.user_type == "1"):


#like

def dashboard(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated
        if (request.user.common_user_data.user_type == "1"):

            return redirect('/agent_dashboard')

        elif (request.user.common_user_data.user_type == "2"):
            return redirect('/user_dashboard')

        else:
            return redirect('/home')

    else:
        return redirect('/login')
```

4. create/save "Common_user_data" object at user registration.
5. Use "signals.py"
   to create your "Common_user_data" model objects automatically at registration/user creation.
6. Frist of all,
   from your post > `Agents have a separate login url and users have a separate login url.`

Yes you can create urls and show them to users.
But how you actually know if user actually a user or agent, if you have known known data of them? until they login.
So actually you have to check the type in views.

So, No need for new auth backends or new user managers.

That's what I use.

Comment: could you please edit it so that it is similar to my code, cause I have come so far that now altering so many lines is a real tough job and I am getting so many errors like I used this line `{% for agent in agents %}` to loop over my agents, now this line doesn't work and is throwing an `OperationalError at /
no such column: users_agent.agent_id`

Comment: I am saying you don't need separate user bases. Use my method. It is more easy to use and develop.

Comment: I can't even perform `python manage.py migrate`. 


It says `The row in table 'users_profile' with primary key '1' has an invalid foreign key: users_profile.user_id contains a value '3' that does not have a corresponding value in users_common_user_data.user_data_id.`

Comment: Ok. Please calm yourself. Tell me did try my method or you are trying to make a separate user base as shown in your code? And you haven't posted users_profile model code?

Comment: I am trying to implement your code brother. If this is more convenient, of course I have to go for this. I have added the `profile` model. Thank You.

Comment: So are you using" Profile" model as "Common_user_data" in my code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256381/discussion-between-pycm-and-jack).

Comment: What is the progress @Jack?